# Lottery Winning number based on blockhash

Tags: solidity, contract-design, security

After reading a lot of Info about this topic in this forum I am asking whether I can just use the formular 
winningNumber = uint256(blockhash(block.number-1)) % 100;
e.g. 10 or 20 blocks after the betting period is finished. The "future" blockhash can not be known by anyone during the betting period right?
e.g. implementing in solidity could be similar to this?
require (block.number > (BettingEndBlock+20);

Comment: You still have the problem that block hashes are controlled by the miner.

Comment: There is not only one valid solution for the mining puzzle (for different nonces you could find another hashblock that fulfill the condition). usually, miners give directly the first valid answer (blockhash&nonce) they found to win the reward before others do... However, they can calculate the winning number and if they want to benefit from your lottery then they could risk it and look after another valid hash that makes them win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is to separate the commitment and the reveal so that no one can "guess" the "solution" from "this" block.

It would be sufficient, I think, to work with block.number + 1, so 100 blocks into the future don't add significant difficulty. Miners will *always* have a slight opportunity to craft blocks a certain way but I think it is negligible.

**Wrong:**

```
function claimPrize(bytes32 solution) public {
  bytes32 check = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.hash));
  require(solution == check, "Incorrect");
  // award prize
}
```

The problem is it is trivial to compute the "solution" in the context of the current block and then collect the prize.

**Commit / Reveal:**

```
function commit(bytes32 committment) public {
  commitments[msg.sender] = commitment; // over-simplified
}

function claimPrize() public {
  require(block.number >= deadline, "lottery still open");
  bytes32 solution = // ... block hash at deadline
  require(committments[msg.sender] == solution, "You didn't win");
  // award prize
}
```

In case it isn't clear, future block hash isn't knowable. The important thing is to ensure that the contest is based on a future block hash, not the present one (or the past).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! the line "require(committments[msg.sender] = solution, "You didn't win");"  was with a double "==" for comparison right? I will use your solution. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Fixed it. :-)

Comment: Update. Miner extracted value is much more organized. Exercise extreme caution and don't assume a miner's odds of doing something you might consider unfair are slim, especially if there are significant financial incentives involved.